# PHP Undefined offset: 0 with isset

Tags: php, undefined, offset, isset

I am trying to understand if it's correct for PHP to throw an undefined offset error when using isset() function.
The data comes from an eloquent collection.

```
$interest->vehicles
```

The problem happens when the collection is empty.
Below code tested on 3 different setups (Mac+Mamp PRO, Windows+Xampp, Mac+Mamp), throws an undefined offset in first  two setups but not in mine which is the third one (Mac+Mamp)
All tested scenarios are done with PHP 7 and display errors On.

```
isset($interest->vehicles[0]['make'])
```

I understand why the error may be happening to the other setups as the offset i try to isset doesn't exist, but the thing i don't understand is why i don't see the error on my setup when using isset.

I also tried to reinstall Mamp on my maching, upgraded to Sierra OS, restarted my laptop, changed php.ini settings to always display all errors .

```
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1043:
Undefined offset: 0 (View: /Users/efood-leo/Sites/cardealer/resources/views/panel/interest/form.blade.php) (View: /Users/efood-leo/Sites/cardealer/resources/views/panel/interest/form.blade.php)
```

This is the error i am talking about, and happens only if i try to retrieve

```
$interest->vehicles[0]['make']
```

When the vehicles[0] does not exist.

if i do :

```
isset($interest->vehicles[0]['make'])
```

Then there is no error in my setup, and 2 other devs report the error still happens with isset.

Comment: if(isset($interest)) {if(count($interest->vehicles) > 0) { var_dump($interest->vehicles; ) } }

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](https://3v4l.org/MBaZW) Please provide the exact error message and implementation of `$interest`.

Comment: Try to just evaluate the result with `if ($interest->vehicles)` without using isset

Comment: I am not trying to fix the issue, i am trying to reproduce the error on my setup which does not produce an error.
I updated with the error message

Comment: @deceze The collection is an empty array
https://3v4l.org/ahjZ2

Comment: Put the following at the top `ini_set('display_errors',1); ` `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try evaluating without isset. Isset checks if the value exists even though it returns 0 it tells isset I'm existing.

Comment: @Epodax
I updated the description, the error is happening on my colleagues setup but is not triggering in my setup.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

Isset() function is returning true somehow so without isset it works

```
$interest = (object)['vehicles' => []];

echo $interest->vehicles[0]['make'];
```

Read more on isset():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I tried it and it seems correct! Still can't figure why my colleagues see an undefined offset error with isset.
https://3v4l.org/aOZOd

Comment: Hope your machine is running the same version of Php. Somehow isset() maybe thinking the error is a value since it is meant to check if the passed argument exists thus it returns nothing. Be careful how you use isset(). If statements are useful for basic evaluations.

Comment: From isset documentation it is clearly said that isset will return false on deeper array values that don't exist:
    var_dump(isset($a['cake']['a']['b']));  // FALSE

Comment: Array keys differ from value....you are accessing the array with an invalid key. Isset would return false if the key exists and the value is null or empty